# How can I mock %ENV in Perl tests?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I'm trying to retrofit some tests using `Test::More` to legacy code and I've bumped into a bit of a snag. I don't seem to be able to set `%ENV` in the test module. The called function definitely uses this variable so `%ENV` doesn't seem to be carried across to the test object.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Test::More qw(no_plan);

BEGIN {
    $ENV{HTTP_WWW_AUTHENTICATE} = 
        'WWW-Authenticate: MyType realm="MyRealm",userid="123",password="abc"';
    use_ok('Util');
}

$ENV{HTTP_WWW_AUTHENTICATE} = 
    'WWW-Authenticate: MyType realm="MyRealm",userid="123",password="abc"';

printf qq{get_authentication_info = "%s"\n}, get_authentication_info();
ok(get_authentication_info(), 'Get authentication info');
```

I keep getting...

```
perl t\Util.t
ok 1 - use Util;
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at t\Util.t line 14.
get_authentication_info = ""
```

As with all things Perl, I'm pretty sure that some one has done this before.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to all for your help

The problem was between the keyboard & chair ... My test data was just plain wrong
It needed to be

```
$ENV{HTTP_WWW_AUTHENTICATE} = 
    'MyType realm="MyRealm",userid="123",password="abc"';
```

Comment: OK the comments are not in the executable... they just show where I tried to set the %ENV WITHOUT the comments.

Comment: Why do you have commented out lines which set the env variable?

Comment: YOu can do other things, like add a comment after the line to indicate it rather than commenting out the problem code.

Comment: My gut says this ain't got nuthin to do with testing or mocking anything.

Comment: Well, I guess this question is no longer relevant then. Voting to close but you might want to delete it.

Comment: I tried to delete this thread but I guess don't have the karma to delete when there are up votes yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does

```
get_authentication_info()
```

return?

My guess is nothing.

If this is always true, then line 14 will always return the "Use of uninitialized value..." warning.

If you expect a value, you need to investigate why get_authentication_info() is failing?

Comment: So what happened exactly? don't leave us in the dark!

Answer (score 4):

As Sinan said, the `$ENV{...}` lines are commented out, so it can't work. But if you want really testable code, I'd suggest to make the `get_authentication_info` function take a hash as an argument. That way you can test it without setting the global variable, and in the real code you can pass the real enviromnent hash. Global state will always become a problem eventually.

Comment: As I said this it legacy code so this is going to be a problem all over

Comment: As long as it's legacy code under your control, you can always refactor it.

Comment: True, but I'm trying to do the "tests before changes" TDD thing

Comment: Sometimes you have to refactor your code before you can adequately test it.  IMO it's one of the best things about TDD: it forces you to think carefully about the architecture of your code and write things modularly. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why are the lines setting `$ENV{HTTP_WWW_AUTHENTICATE}` commented out?

Also, what are the specs for `get_authentication_info()`?

Comment: This is demo code... the comments just show where I tried setting the %ENV hash.

Comment: Setting `$ENV{HTTP_WWW_AUTHENTICATE}` worked just find when I tried it, you must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: @telesphore4: Well, don't post commented out code. Post the code you actually try to run instead of relying on others' capacity to deduce what you are or are not doing. If I had to guess, I would say the problem is in `get_authentication_info()`.

Comment: You were able to access the test code in the test module? If so, then please post your test code.

Comment: @telesphore4: I think you got this wrong: You need to show more information.

Comment: Last comment is correct. Thank you. I tried reducing the client code and found a problem in the test. Accepted because you stuck to your guns on the telesphore4 has messed something else up

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with Lukáš -- get your global environment (and perform validity checks etc) all in one place, such as in its own method, and then pass those values to all other methods that need it. That way in your unit tests you can just drop in a replacement method that determines the environment and config variables in a different way (such as from a file, or directly set at the top of your test script).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the env variable before BEGIN.

If not try this:

1. First, go to a command prompt and set the env var there. Then run your script. If the tests pass. Then as you predicted, the problem is with setting the env var.
2. If the tests fail, then the problem lies some where else (probably in `get_authentication_info`).

Comment: I tried the literal "before the BEGIN block> No good. Perl executes the BEGIN block before anything else... so where would I put that exactly.

Comment: Yes, BEGIN is executed before other code, but I was guessing maybe it's executed in a different context so the env var doesn't survive after BEGIN execution. But obviously I was wrong. :)
I added simple plan to test your code. Did you try it?